# Why can't we use the preprocessor to create custom-delimited strings?

Tags: c, gcc, macros, clang, c-preprocessor

I was playing around a bit with the **C** preprocessor, when something which seemed so simple failed:

```
#define STR_START "
#define STR_END "

int puts(const char *);

int main() {
    puts(STR_START hello world STR_END);
}
```

When I compile it with gcc (note: similar errors with clang), it fails, with these errors:

```
$ gcc test.c
test.c:1:19: warning: missing terminating " character
test.c:2:17: warning: missing terminating " character
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:7: error: missing terminating " character
test.c:7: error: ‘hello’ undeclared (first use in this function)
test.c:7: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
test.c:7: error: for each function it appears in.)
test.c:7: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘world’
test.c:7: error: missing terminating " character
```

Which sort of confused me, so I ran it through the pre-processor:

```
$ gcc -E test.c
# 1 "test.c"
# 1 ""
# 1 ""
# 1 "test.c"
test.c:1:19: warning: missing terminating " character
test.c:2:17: warning: missing terminating " character

int puts(const char *);

int main() {
    puts(" hello world ");
}
```

Which, despite the warnings, produces *completely valid code (in the bolded text)!*

If, macros in **C** are simply a textual replace, why is it that my initial example would fail? Is this a compiler bug? If not, where in the standards does it have information pertaining to this scenario?

<sub>Note: I am **not** looking for how to make my initial snippet compile. I am simply looking for info on why this scenario fails.</sub>

Comment: Your question title is somewhat wrong. You can use the preprocesor to create customized strings. It is just your attempt to do so is wrong. There is a special operator for this, `#` called stringification.

Comment: @JensGustedt No, that's not a custom delimited string, just a string from an argument. Rolled back.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that even though the code expands to `" hello, world "`, it's not being recognized as a single *string literal* token by the preprocessor; instead, it's being recognized as the (invalid) *sequence* of tokens `"`, `hello`, `,`, `world`, `"`.

[N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> **6.4 Lexical elements**
> ...
> 3 A *token* is the minimal lexical element of the language in translation phases 7 and 8. The
> categories of tokens are: keywords, identiﬁers, constants, string literals, and punctuators.
> A preprocessing token is the minimal lexical element of the language in translation
> phases 3 through 6. The categories of preprocessing tokens are: header names,
> identiﬁers, preprocessing numbers, character constants, string literals, punctuators, and
> single non-white-space characters that do not lexically match the other preprocessing
> token categories.<sup>69)</sup> **If a `'` or a `"` character matches the last category, the behavior is
> undeﬁned**. Preprocessing tokens can be separated by white space; this consists of
> comments (described later), or white-space characters (space, horizontal tab, new-line,
> vertical tab, and form-feed), or both. As described in 6.10, in certain circumstances
> during translation phase 4, white space (or the absence thereof) serves as more than
> preprocessing token separation. White space may appear within a preprocessing token
> only as part of a header name or between the quotation characters in a character constant
> or string literal.
>
> ---
>
> <sup>69) An additional category, placemarkers, is used internally in translation phase 4 (see 6.10.3.3); it cannot
> occur in source ﬁles.</sup>

Note that neither `'` nor `"` are punctuators under this definition.

Comment: Very interesting. I'm honestly surprised that the compiler *doesn't* accept this, seeing as how lenient gcc can be in regards to UB.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII, the lexing phase of C is very strict. Violation of syntax rules is not accepted by C compilers. These are constraint violation that require a diagnostic. And then, don't forget that for stringification there is a special operator `#`, so there is no need for such constructs.

Comment: This is bizarre. In fact a traditional C compiler would have accepted this because it gets relexed after the preprocessor step. Then again, traditional C used to expand macros in string constants, which was almost universally regarded as bad.

Answer (score 8):

The preprocessor runs in [multiple phases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Phases).  Phase 3, tokenization, occurs before expansion, so preprocessor macros must represent full tokens.  In your case, `STR_START` and `STR_END` are tokenized and then substituted, which makes those tokens invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
#define STR_START "
```

compiler expects *string literal*. String literal must end with closing quote. That's why compiler complains about missing terminating `"` character.

After macro expansion compiler complains again, because invalid tokens.

---

For example, MSVC compiler complains in other words:

```
error C2001: newline in constant
```

and after expansion it complains about missing quotes.